# Why is my web application's memory usage so high?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, iis-express, perfmon

I have a C# MVC App that also uses EF.

It's working well but on my local dev machine IIS Express uses in the order of 100Mb of memory, but when its in the production environment it uses 600mb of memory and seems to be challenging the specs of our VPS.

The 600mb is taken from PerfMons private bytes counter on the app pool process. RedGates performance monitor however seems to say the private bytes is more in the order of 150mb - I'm not sure what the difference between the two measures is.

What is a reasonable guide to private bytes usage that should I expect PerfMon to report for a production site?

I read somewhere that private bytes may be reporting memory that is available to the application not necessarily memory that is currently allocated by the application.  I still find it alarming that it has reached 500-600mb - presumably the OS must think the applications memory demand may peak there?

Should I be alarmed and any advice on how to figure out what is going on?

UPDATE
If I run it on Win7 with IIS it only consumes around 100mb.  Similar to result from IIS Express - so does this mean its something more to do with the IIS configuration on my production machine?

Comment: Does the memory grow over time? How much memory does the server have?  When you first start the application is the memory at 120M and then it grows to 600M? What type of data is the application dealing with (large objects?)?

Comment: The best you can do is to take full memory dump of your process on production environment and investigate it using WinDBG or other tools (.NET Memory Profiler allows that I believe)

Comment: The machine has 2gb of memory.  If I recycle the app pool it starts at 16mb but visiting one page seems to immediately make it go to 230mb.  There are about 30 normal kind f tables, there is some large data but it hasn't been touched at this point.  Within 24 hours it'll be up around 400+mb.

Comment: I think it may be normal. Try expanding your virtual memory. .NET works best with plenty of it. We have an application with 4000 users. It was maxing out the server's 8 GB of memory. I increased the swap file to 16GB. Application runs smoothly now.